# LINQ Join method

Tags: c#, linq, join

got 3 classes,

```
public calss Employee
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
  }   

public class Sale
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and DB class which initiate a list of employees and sales and contain methods involving LINQ queries:

one of the methods, need to get a year and bring me back all the employees made a sale that year , now at the last Select I want to get from the joined list only the employee object without putting the properties myself, and ofc creating a distinct so I won't have duplicates, here where I got so far, I'd love for some help, because I'm getting error notifications:

```
        public List<Employee> GetEmployeesMadeSale(int year)
        {
            var emploSales =
                Employees.Join(
                Sales,
                e => e.ID,     //empID = e.ID, Amount = s.Amount
                s => s.EmpID,
                (e, s) => new { Emplo = e, Year = s.Date.Year })
                .Where(es => es.Year == year)
                .Select(es => new Employee() = es.Emplo)
                .ToList(); 

            //return emploSales
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Select`

```
.Select(es => new Employee() = es.Emplo)
```

Try doing this instead

```
.Select(es => es.Emplo)
```